# Spinner data sorting in Android

Tags: android

I have spinner with array list thats work fine, but i want to sort out the datas from a to z (example: apple,ball,cat,dog...)order. I submit my code below

```
    ArrayList<String> SourceArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Spinner Sourcespinner;// = new Spinner(this);
    Sourcespinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> SourceArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,SourceArray);
    SourceArrayAdapter.add("Chennai");
    SourceArrayAdapter.add("Mumbai");
    SourceArrayAdapter.add("Kolkatta");
    SourceArrayAdapter.add("Delhi");
    Sourcespinner.setAdapter(SourceArrayAdapter);`
```

I don't know how to do sorting for this

Comment: [See this Tuts...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

Comment: i hope it is possible using textwatcher,,

Comment: you can do that with an edittext and addTextChangedListener but just spinner I don't have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this to sort your data

```
Collections.sort(SourceArray);
```

Comment: yes , i got it ,, is it possible to show the list of particular alphabet if i pressed particular alphabet (example: if i press f is it possible to display the list starting with f that means fat,fit,fog like that)

Comment: I am not sure to do that easly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data to the ArrayList and just use the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class to sort for you:

```
Collections.sort(SourceArray);
```

If you need to add your own objects they need to implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and implement the method [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29). When changing the ArrayList's data make sure to notify the adapter that new data might have been added by using this code:

```
SourceArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i studied tat document. i can able to understood the concept but can't able to implement the interface.