# how to sort data alphabetically in spinner

Tags: android

i am new in android field and i want to sort my spinner data alphabetically. please help

**note:- i am receiving data from web services.**

my code is:-

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAtlasContactSignup"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editCompanySignup"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/slect_box1x"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:prompt="@string/atlas_contact" />

 private void initializeSpinner(ArrayList<AtlasContact> atlastContacts) {

    ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atlastContacts);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinnerAtlasContact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here `AtlasContact` is a class which accepts the data coming from web services.

Comment: This is a common question, understand that some people will probably downvote you since this basic question has been asked so many times.

Comment: ok i ll remove it as m new to android n stackoverflow too so i have no idea. :(

Comment: Well, there are answers now so you cannot delete it, but for the moment no one has downvoted this. Maybe those people won't notice. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spinner data sorting in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468547/spinner-data-sorting-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are fetching the values from the **SQLite DB** then their works the query to **sort** the values alphabetically and put them sorted in an ARRAY.

**or** Try to add data to the **ArrayList** and just use the **Collections class** to sort for you::

```
Collections.sort(SourceArray);
```

Also,

**Comparable** interface and implement the method **compareTo()**

Comment: its showing following error:---> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<AtlasContact>). The inferred type AtlasContact is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>

Answer (score 6):

You just need to sort your source:

```
Collections.sort(atlastContacts, new Comparator<AtlasContact>(){
  public int compare(AtlasContact a1, AtlasContact a2) {
    return a1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getName());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Collections.sort(atlastContacts);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked docs? There is sort method in `ArrayAdapter`.

You just need to implement your own `Comparator`. I guess it's just:

```
int compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.compareTo(s2); }
```